# Java Organisational Chart Data Structure

Tags: java, charts, tree

I am writing a project to create organisational charts from Active Directory where if you give the program a list of names (employees) the root node is the lowest common manager for those employees. This could be the real top manager of the organization, or a department manager, it varies depending on the names.

I can use active directory manager attributes to retrieve manager names, and currently I run through each employee getting their manager until the top is reached creating an ArrayList... then I need a way to compare the lists to identify the common manager. I did this using List.contains() for just two people, but this isn't scalable to more than 2 people. Any suggestions here?

I wish to create a tree data structure with the common manager as the root node, which contains all the people in the lists below the common manager, and their parent-child relationships.

Which data structure would be suitable for this?

Comment: something like www.orgchartasp.net ?

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet yes, that kind of layout. My main problem is choosing a data structure then working out the common manager.

Comment: fine i dont have the data structure, but can help you with the above component, as i wrote it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is overkill, but personally I'd recommend you use an embedded Neo4j db, it's really good for this type of structure and querying.   Very scalable and fast.

Comment: That looks good, but first for at least a POC i wanted to go basic and just use a collection of objects.